# LAST_INSERT_ID after restarting MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to retrieve the `LAST_INSERT_ID` by following statements after inserting a new record, it works fine.

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

**The problem**

When Inserting a new record in table and restart MySQL Server and then trying to retrieve `LAST_INSERT_ID`, it gets `0` value!

`LAST_INSERT_ID` just works before restarting MySQL or rebooting system ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID is session specific, so, new session, new id (or none at all)

Comment: Why don't you just get the ID regular way?

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID returns last executed SQL Query's inserted id only.

Comment: You can get by MAX(PRIMARY_KAY)

Comment: select your table by using max(id) which is inserted latest

Comment: You got the downvotes because you wanted to use `LAST_INSERT_ID` without using an `INSERT` statement before that. That demonstrates lack of knowledge. That implies that you need to use a different method for obtaining the value you need, but you got stuck on `LAST_INSERT_ID` method. That's the [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as stated in [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id),

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a **per-connection basis**. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client. This value cannot be affected by other clients, even if they generate AUTO_INCREMENT values of their own. This behavior ensures that each client can retrieve its own ID without concern for the activity of other clients, and without the need for locks or transactions.

Which means - after restart for your set of statements there is no statement affecting AUTO_INCREMENT value, so the value is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

See this text in the [`LAST_INSERT_ID`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) manual page:

```
The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis.
```

If you restart the server, or disconnect and reconnect againg, then you are not using the same connection as when you did the insert, so that's why you get `0`

Answer (score 1):

As it was already stated based on *MySQL Reference Manual*: **[function_last-insert-id](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)**:

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a
>   *per-connection basis*. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) value generated for most recent statement affecting an [AUTO_INCREMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html) column *by that client*.

To get what you need, just make a new query:

`SELECT MAX(ID) FROM ExampleTable;`

in case you can't use *LAST_INSERT_ID* in the intended way.